# VS Code - Hide Closing Bracket When Code Block is Folded

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I'm using Visual Studio Code and looking for a way to hide the closing bracket of a code block when that code block is folded, can't seem to find a setting for that, the code just looks wrong to me since I'm used to the Visual Studio IDE which has this behavior.

Current Behavior

[image: Current Behavior]

Expected Behavior

[image: Expected Behavior]

Comment: I think the reason it's this way is so you can differentiate between function header declarations (for instance in a C++ header files or Java Abstract Classes) and the actual function definition.

Comment: @UdoE. as C++ function definitions and Java's abstract methods don't use curly brackets since they don't have a body, and since folded code blocks are hinted at with those three dots in VS Code, isn't that enough of a difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install Explicit Folding on VS code and past this settings on JSON file and Enjoy...

```
    "explicitFolding.rules": {
    "javascript": [
        {
            "begin": "{",
            "end": "}"
        },
        {
            "begin": "`",
            "end": "`"
        },
        {
            "foldLastLine": true
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: WOW! What a great quality of life improvement in such a little way. I've been looking to solve this little irritation for years, and it turns out that not only do many other people have the same itch, but someone actually scratched it. Great suggestion, @lisan-e.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3352 [folding] Collapse ending brace to the same line #3352.  It doesn't look like it is being worked on.

But in the issue (near the end) is mention of an extension [explicit folding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding) which you might try to get what you want.